# Xcode 6.1.1 - commit update faded and unable to use source control

Tags: ios, xcode, git, svn

Please help us setting up `xcode` in order to use with our `svn repository`.

We have our `svn repository` on local server 192.168.1.xx IP and we `check out` via `http` (http://192.168.1.xx/svn/xproject), I have mac mini which was upgraded with Yosemite. Ever since upgradation, `Xcode (6.1.1)` is not allowing to commit or update but only checkout is possible. Other options are in faded mode.

We used to have `xcode 4.2` which worked fine. Please suggest what is step-by-step procedure to fix this problem and xcode for commit and update.

Are we missing any depending components to use `xcode`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to setup remote source control path? Like,

Goto Menu > Source Control > YOUR_REPO -- BRANCH > Configure YOUR_REPO (select this).

From this, you will get 3 tabbed window, 2nd one is for Report svn configuration. Please setup you `svn` repo path here.

May this help you.

Comment: Sorry, there is not an option to select REPO since 'Source control' gives only Checkout option. Other options are faded out. I cannot select any repo. any other suggestions? BTB my svn and Xcode svn both are 1.7.9 version.

Comment: Have you made any changes, in current project??, if not then just check out your last build, and, it will allow you to commit and push, coz it has set up remote.

Comment: As you see in this image, http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/t10_7_disabled_source_control.jpg

Comment: We even did reinstall OSX thinking there could have been something wrong. But it did not help. Also installed command line tools without success.

Comment: Have you added Account/Repository from Preference of Xcode?

Comment: Yes, account added in preferences.

Comment: @Anilkasibhatta Repository added?

Comment: We've tried to add repository by using 'checkout' but it does not work. Prior to this, we've used ln -s /opt/local/bin/svn and moved all svn folders from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin. Would it ruin the situation?

Comment: Without SVN setup with xcode, the last change will not affect anything